# How do I display the value of a cell in one column based on the value of a cell in a different column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a simple table.

Column A are dates (rows 2 to 100) that reflect approximately the next 3 months.

Column C are percentages that range from 0 to 1 (i.e. 0% to 100%). The %s are derived from a =FORECAST function.

I want to query a date in column A based on a value of 100% in column C. However, the QUERY function does not work because it's reading the =FORECAST formula in column C rather than the text or value of "100%" itself. (In other words, if I remove the =FORECAST formula and type in the string "100%", the query works.

How can I pull the date value in Column A and keep the formulas used in column C?

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a lookup to find the value in column `A` on the first row where column `C` contains the value `100%`. Try this:

`=vlookup(100%, { C2:C, A2:A }, 2, false)`

In the event multiple rows in column `C` may contain `100%`, and you want to get all such dates, try this:

`=filter(A2:A, C2:C = 100%)`

In the event your `forecast()` numbers do not produce exact percentages but figures like `100.04%`, use this:

`=filter(Forecast!A2:A, round(Forecast!C2:C, 2) = 100%)`

Comment: I get a #REF error using the vLookup, and an #N/A error using the filter function. Please note that I have edited my original question because I was able to get a =QUERY statement to work (kind of). Love the quick help this website provides!! Thanks you guys!

Comment: The `#REF!` could be a circular reference, a misspelled range, or any number of similar issues. The `#N/A` typically tells that the search key `100%` does not appear in column `A`. That can happen if you have formatted the column as **Format > Number > Plain text**. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Sample spreadsheet . . .

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sXT90NbZW_GhS-IzOnB0zHcIKFdARv5BTe6mr3hA7s4/edit#gid=1864234985

Comment: The result from `forecast()` that looks like `100%` is actually `100.040242516%`. Format the cell with more decimals to see the actual results. The functions `vlookup()` and `filter()` expect an _exact_ match. Edited the answer to include a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who contributed. My workaround was replacing the = sign with a > sign, as shown:

=QUERY(StageHist!A:H, "SELECT A WHERE C>.99")

since I couldn't figure out how to make the 100% figure an exact 100%. Apparently the =FORECAST formula is designed to give a result with 8 or 9 digits to the right of the decimal. (Although I'm sure that I could nest a =ROUNDing function inside of FORECAST and get an exact 1.0 value. (A project for another day!)